# Drag and drop list with hierarchy/nested behavior

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I only want to do this with vanilla javascript. But if there is some lightweight library I might reconsider. Anyway, I basically want to emulate a file system with a list of elements.

```
<div class="container" >
   <div class="item draggable" draggable> First </div>
   <div class="children-nodes">
       <div class="container" >
           <div class="item draggable" draggable> First </div>
           <div class="children-nodes">
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in my HTML structure. Each container can be dragged and placed inside another .children-nodes, however the items themselves can also be dragged and moved around in the hierarchy. There are multiple of these containers with items nested inside eachother. I have written several algorithms to try to make this work I just can't seem to make it happen. I get errors like "new child contains parent" and etc.

Here's the latest logic i tried:

```
const draggables = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');

draggables.forEach(draggable => {
    draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
        draggable.classList.add('is-dragging');
    })

    draggable.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
        draggable.classList.remove('is-dragging');
    })

    draggable.addEventListener('dragover', (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation()
        event.preventDefault();

        if(!draggable.classList.contains('.is-dragging')){
            const item = document.querySelector('.is-dragging');
            const containerOfItem = document.querySelector('.container:has(.is-dragging)');
            const childrenContainer = containerOfItem.querySelector('.children-nodes');
            const children = childrenContainer.querySelectorAll('div');
            if(children.length == 0) {
                const childrenDropContainer = draggable.parentNode.querySelector('.children-nodes');
                childrenDropContainer.appendChild(containerOfItem);
            } else {
                
            }
        }
    })
})
```

And like I said. I've written it multiple different ways. I changed the markup too and searched around for some information. The kind of help that I would want would be what to consider, in which direction should I move, how do I solve this problem. Any help is gladly received.

Comment: Not sure if it fits all your needs, but have a look at this one https://github.com/tobyzerner/inclusive-sort

Comment: Ye I'll give it a go and see if I can work something out. Thank you.

Comment: @exside Ye I just took a look at it and built something. This is nothing I coulnd't already do with vanilla js myself, but thank you for taking you time to try.